# how to add read more button on wordpress post without inserting any read more tag

Tags: wordpress

I want to add read more button after 70 or 100 words. if any special case will occur in this word interval it will be considered. ie:
after 65 word read more text while creating post. Any idea? I am apologizing if I am requesting a very novice type help. I am new wordpress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add read more button automatically in wordpress post editing visual editor or front end please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add this code in function.php

```
function get_the_frontpage_excerpt($count){
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">more</a>';
    return $excerpt;
}
```

You can call below function with words length in post templates anywhere.

```
echo get_the_frontpage_excerpt(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes it works, great!  Again, thanks a ton. Up voted :)

Answer (score 1):

functions.php :

```
function yourtheme_get_the_excerpt($word_limit) {

    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

    $words = explode(' ', $excerpt, ($word_limit + 1));

        if(count($words) > $word_limit)
        {
          array_pop($words);

          return implode(' ', $words)."...";
        } else {
          //otherwise
          return implode(' ', $words);
        }

} //end of function
```

index.php / home.php / archive.php  : [ Anywhere the post loop is written ]

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

   <?php yourtheme_get_the_excerpt(65); //65= word limit ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="theme-btn-purple"><?php esc_html_e('read more','textdomain'); ?></a>

endwhile;
```

Hope this will help you.